# Can totally inhomogeneous sets of reals coexist with determinacy?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, gn.general-topology, descriptive-set-theory

A special case of a theorem of Brian Scott (from [*On the existence of totally inhomogeneous spaces*](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1975-051-02/S0002-9939-1975-0375262-5/S0002-9939-1975-0375262-5.pdf)) is that there is a size-continuum set $S\subset\mathbb{R}$ such that if $x,y\in S$ are distinct then $S\setminus\{x\}\not\cong S\setminus\{y\}$. The proof relies heavily on the axiom of choice, and at a glance any such $S$ must be quite wild. However, I don't immediately see how to show that such an $S$ must fail any of the standard regularity properties (e.g. measurability).

> **Question**: Is the existence of such an $S$ consistent with $\mathsf{ZF+DC+AD}$?

"Obviously" the answer is negative ...

Comment: A related question (I do not know the answer either):  Is there an infinite Borel subset of $ℝ$ that does not have a nontrivial auto-homeomorphism?

Comment: It appears that the question was answered by van Engelen, Miller, and Steel, see [this review](https://zbmath.org/0646.03045).

Comment: @KPHart Delightful! If you add that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: What structure does the $\cong$ refer to?

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Homeomorphism as topological spaces. (See Scott's paper.)

Comment: I see, thanks .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In *Rigid Borel sets and better quasiorder theory* (Logic and combinatorics, Proc. AMS-IMS-SIAM Conf., Arcata/Calif. 1985, Contemp. Math. 65, 199-222 (1987), [zbMath review here](https://zbmath.org/0646.03045)) Fons van Engelen, Arnold Miller, and John Steel showed that the only rigid Borel sets are the singletons; the proof yields the same for all sets of reals if one assumes $\mathsf{AD}$.
So the answer to the present question is negative.